# Extracting key from a json

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

Given this JSON snippet, I'm trying to figure out to extract the name of the key corresponding to a specific "instance-id" using jq.

I'm trying this:

```
jq '.machines | keys as $x | if .[]."instance-id"=="wdc7ae" then <some-code-to-get-the-key>  else empty end'
```

where $x has all machine numbers. and "wdc7ae" is the specific "instance-id" value

```html
{
  "model": {
    "name": "maas2",
    "controller": "ctr-xenial",
    "cloud": "maas",
    "version": "2.0.1"
  },
  "machines": {
    "1": {
      "dns-name": "10.4.0.181",
      "instance-id": "wdc7ae",
      "series": "xenial"
    },
    "2": {
      "dns-name": "10.4.0.182",
      "instance-id": "7mx74d",
      "series": "xenial"
    },
    "3": {
      "dns-name": "10.4.0.183",
      "instance-id": "rgn3ca",
      "series": "xenial"
    },
    "4": {
      "dns-name": "10.4.0.184",
      "instance-id": "kmy4bh",
      "series": "xenial"
    },
    "5": {
      "dns-name": "10.4.0.185",
      "instance-id": "eb38c7",
      "series": "xenial"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks 'Goldfish' from #jq irc channel. Here's the command that 'Goldfish' shared and working like a charm for me:

```
.machines | to_entries[] | select(.value."instance-id" == "wdc7ae").key
```